# Counting the elements on a line

Tags: c++, arrays, string, iterator

So, I want to count the elements on a line from an input .dat file; it's got like, hundreds of lines and I want to store the data in a 2-D vector, or array, so I want to work out how many 'columns' the array should have.

My current thoughts are, grab just a single line, set it up with some counter in a loop, and iterate through until the end of the line is reached, and then just push the value stored by the counter as a variable and initialise the array and whatever, but, is there a more elegant solution? It just seems like a fair amount of code to do something, that to me, seems very basic, but I haven't been able to track down anything better from searching around.

Comment: So your goal is put each line to an array/vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rolling with the 2-D vector (which I assume means a `std::vector<std::vector<double> >`, and under the assumption that the data is usually well-formed (i.e., a rectangular matrix is in the file), I'd just parse the file linewise into vectors and throw in a check afterwards if all lines had the same length. In this scenario, there's no need for you to work out the extents of the matrix before memory allocation because every line gets its own piece of memory. It could look something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<double> > parse_file(std::istream &in) {
  std::string line;
  // istringstream is something you feed a string to read from it like you
  // would from a file or std::cin.
  std::istringstream parser;
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> result;

  while(std::getline(in, line)) {
    parser.clear();
    parser.str(line);

    // read stuff into a vector at the end of the vector vector. The
    // istream_iterators make this easy by making the stringstream accessible
    // like a range of doubles.       
    result.emplace_back(std::istream_iterator<double>(parser),
                        std::istream_iterator<double>(      ));
  }

  // check if there are two lines in the matrix that don't have the same
  // length. That would probably be bad. If that would not be bad, omit this.
  if(std::adjacent_find(result.begin(),
                        result.end(),
                        [](std::vector<double> const &lhs,
                           std::vector<double> const &rhs) {
                          return lhs.size() != rhs.size();
                        }) != result.end()) {
    throw std::logic_error("Input file does not contain a rectangular matrix");
  }

  return result;
}

...

std::ifstream in("foo.dat");
auto matrix = parse_file(in);
```

Comment: Haha, this looks great. Thank you. Is it incorrect to call it a 2D vector or whatever?

Comment: No, not incorrect. It's just that the term is ambiguous -- it could also mean a flat vector that you address in a certain way, for example (that is mirroring what 2D arrays are).